# How to select a count of rows after a specific flag has been set

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I want to get a count of rows, but ending at the most recent date (which exists in the table) and starts at a certain Bit. Right now I'm just trying to get a select working so I can see the data I'm pulling is correct(which right now it isn't).

I want `isReset` to be the starting point, and `Date_Time` to be the end point in my group for the count. Is this possible?

My select statement right now looks like this, and it is wrong because It's just getting every row with `isReset` instead of starting from there, but that's also where I am stuck.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE WHERE (isReset = 1) AND (Date_Time <= '2015-11-30')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to find the date, and then use that in the `where` clause.  Something like this:

```
select count(*)
from t
where t.date_time > (select max(date_time) from t where isReset = 1);
```

Comment: You I'm guessing the reset should be included and that you should use `>=`.